# What are scars useful for?

Tags: haskell, zipper

In the paper titled "The Zipper" by Huet, he also mentions scars as a variation of zippers. Compared to zippers, which became pretty well known in the Haskell community, scars are pretty much unheard of. There is very little information about them in the paper itself and anywhere on the internet from what I could find.

So I have to ask, are they just not useful at all or is there something they are useful for, but most people just don't know about them?

Comment: You can find some information in this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990689/how-do-i-code-a-tree-of-objects-in-haskell-with-pointers-to-parent-and-children

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a minor adjustment to the tree type to make certain operations more efficient.

The paper focuses (ha ha) on *rose trees* - trees whose nodes have an arbitrary number of children. The code from the paper is in OCaml but translating it to Haskell doesn't require much adjustment:

```
data Rose a = Leaf a | Rose [Rose a]
```

To briefly recap, the idea of zippers is to represent a *position* in a data structure by its *context*. The context of a node in a rose tree consists of the path you took down the tree to reach the node's parent, and the path you took along the list of siblings to reach the node itself.

```
data Path a = Top | Node (Path a) [Rose a] [Rose a]

data Pos a = Pos { focus :: Rose a, path :: Path a }
```

This allows you to zoom in on a position in a tree without forgetting where you've been by walking `right` and `down`, and then rebuild the tree by retreating `left` and zooming out `up`.

```
right, down, left, up :: Pos a -> Maybe (Pos a)
right (Pos _ Top) = Nothing
right (Pos _ (Node _ _ [])) = Nothing
right (Pos t (Node p ls (r:rs))) = Just $ Pos r (Node p (t:ls) rs)

down (Pos (Leaf _) _) = Nothing
down (Pos (Rose []) _) = Nothing
down (Pos (Rose (t:ts)) p) = Just $ Pos t (Node p [] ts)

left (Pos _ Top) = Nothing
left (Pos _ (Node _ [] _)) = Nothing
left (Pos t (Node p (l:ls) rs) = Just $ Pos l (Node p ls (t:rs))

up (Pos _ Top) = Nothing
up (Pos t (Node p l r)) = Just $ Pos (Rose (l ++ t:r)) p
```

Look at the definition of `up`. It takes `t`, `l`, and `r` - the currently focused node and its siblings - and smashes them together into a single list of children. It forgets which node you were looking at. Accordingly, `down` focuses you on the left-most child of the current focus. If you need to go `up` and then back down to the previously focused node you have to walk `right` along the list back to where you were, which is an *O(n)* operation.

Huet's idea of leaving 'scars' in the tree is about making it more convenient to return to a previously focused child. He equips the `Rose` constructor with a focus of its own, replacing the list of children with a list zipper.

```
data SRose a =  -- for "scarred rose"
      SLeaf a
    | SEmpty  -- replaces (Rose [])
    | SRose [SRose a] (SRose a) [SRose a]
```

The `Path` and `Pos` types remain unchanged:

```
data SPath a = STop | SNode (SPath a) [SRose a] [SRose a]
data SPos a = SPos { sfocus :: Rose a, spath :: SPath a }
```

Now, when you go `up` and then back `down`, you don't forget what you were previously looking at.

```
up' (SPos _ STop) = Nothing
up' (SPos t (SNode p l r)) = Just $ SPos (SRose l t r) p

down' (SPos (SLeaf _) _) = Nothing
down' (SPos SEmpty _) = Nothing
down' (SPos (SRose l t r) p) = Just $ SPos t (SNode p l r)
```

Comment: Interesting. But aren't scars then just combined zippers? Because now you replaced the list in the Rose tree with a list zipper.

Comment: @TheRedFox Exactly.